# glDrawPixels() with 0.375 translation

Tags: winapi, opengl, 2d

I've noticed some strange behaviour with glDrawPixels() when using a 0.375 translation. This is my GL initialization:

```
width = 640; height = 480;
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity( );
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity( );
glTranslatef(0.375, 0.375, 0.0);
```

Now I want to draw a 640x30 pixel buffer to the very last 30 rows of my GL window. Hence, I do the following:

```
glRasterPos2i(0, 480);
glDrawPixels(640, 30, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelbuffer);
```

Unfortunately, nothing gets drawn using this code. glGetError() also returns 0. The interesting thing is that as soon as I remove the call to glTranslatef(0.375, 0.375, 0.0) everything works fine!

So could somebody explain to me why this 0.375 translation on both axes confuses glDrawPixels()? Is this somehow rounded to 1.0 internally making my call to glDrawPixels() suddenly want to draw beyond the context's boundaries and thus it gets clipped by OpenGL? This is the only explanation I can think of but I don't understand why OpenGL should round a 0.375 translation to 1.0... it should be rounded down to 0.0 instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why do you assume that rounding is taking place? The pipeline is fully floating-point, the only time rounding would matter here is when you snap the window-space position to a pixel location for rasterization. Your issue occurs ***before*** this even happens, it is related to *clipping*. Ultimately, `glWindowPos2i (...)` would be a better solution, as described in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use glWindowPos2i() because that's OpenGL 1.4 and I need to support an earlier version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point (0,480) actually straddles one of your clipping planes given your projection matrix.  Your sub-pixel shift hack pushes the point beyond the breaking point and the raster position is clipped. In GL, `glRasterPos (...)` will invalidate all following raster operations as long as the initial position is clipped (which in this case, it is).

You could try `glRasterPos2i (0, 479)`. This is altogether more meaningful given the dimensions of your window anyway. You could also drop the whole charade and use `glWindowPos2i (...)` instead of relying on your projection and modelview matrices to position the raster coordinate in window-space.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation makes sense. So we end up with 480.375 which then gets clipped because it is > 480.0. One more question, though: Why do you say that glRasterPos2i(0, 479) is more meaningful? My window's height is 480 pixels so I have to start drawing from y-rasterpos 480. If I start from 479, there'll be a blank line at the window's bottom.

Comment: If you are going to shift the pixel coordinate +.375 in the Y direction, the only possible meaningful location for the raster pos is 479. If you made your shift (+.375,-.375) then it would make sense. I am not exactly sure why you need this sub-pixel shift though?

Comment: The major problem here is that your projection matrix is flipping the Y-axis, ordinarily (e.g. `glOrtho (0, width, 0, height, 0, 1)`) this coordinate could be described as (0,0) and then the shift would also make sense.

Comment: Actually, using 0.375 instead of -0.375 seems to have been the problem in the first place here. I took this 0.375 shift idea from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374282(v=vs.85).aspx because I experienced some "one pixel off" problems with graphics primitives which this 0.375 shift apparently solved. But I didn't see that the example on MSDN doesn't use a flipped axis... but with a flipped Y axis I need -0.375 of course. I have now changed it to +.375/-.375 and now it works fine!

Comment: It's still a little strange, though, because strictly speaking, I am still drawing beyond the breaking point, but on the x-axis now. With the +.375/-.375 translation I'm now drawing from 0.375 to 640.375 so theoretically speaking, it *should* get clipped and nothing should be drawn.... but it doesn't get clipped... everything is drawn just fine. Strange...

Comment: @Andreas: Nope, it's 479. In a raster with N positions (or array of N elements), with the first position being labeled 0, the last position is N-1 – you fell for a typical off-by-1 error.

Comment: @datenwolf: That's what one would naturally expect but I can only repeat that when drawing a 640x480 pixel buffer to a 640x480 viewport using glRasterPos2i(0, 479) the last line of the view port will be left blank while drawing using glRasterPos2i(0, 480) fills the entire view port. No translation is in place. Maybe it's because of the flipped Y axis? I don't know as I'm just about to learn OpenGL but that's the way it is here... moving raster pos to 479 and then drawing a 640x480 pixel buffer definitely leaves a blank line at the bottom...

Comment: @Andreas: No, with +.375,-.375 you are setting a raster position at X=0.375. This is within the bounds of your clipped coordinate space. The dimensions of your `glDrawPixels (...)` are actually irrelevant (and thus, the final X location does not matter), clipping only messes things up when your initial raster position is clipped.

Comment: The sub-pixel shift is as the linked article mentions really only relevant for geometric primitives, since you are rasterizing exact pixels you do not need this. You do not need it for this particular use-case, but done correctly it will not hurt anything and will keep geometric positions properly aligned to integer coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Then I'll just set translation to 0/0 when drawing pixel buffers. Just one more question to get this straight: If the y axis is flipped as it is in my GL context, then I'll have to use +.375/-.375 instead of +.375/+.375 to workaround "one pixel off" issues with gfx primitives, right?

Comment: That is correct, otherwise you will be shifting them the wrong direction. If you tried to draw a triangle that covered specific window-space coordinates the triangle might be off-by-1 pixel vertically if you used +.375/+.375. Things get really interesting if you consider lines, they are rasterized using a [***diamond-shaped grid***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627092(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of the normal top-left coverage for polygons. That is the reason the article says this: *"... while moving line vertices close enough to the pixel centers."*

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question on why `glTranslatef` stops `glDrawPixels` from working, but I can tell you that isn't the way to select where to draw. Check the [man page for `glDrawPixels`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) for a bit more info. It will tell you about [`glRasterPos`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) and [`glWindowPos`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glWindowPos.xml)

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on what exactly you think is wrong with my way of using glDrawPixels()? Just pointing me to the manual is not really helpful, especially because I'm actually using glDrawPixels() quite often in my project and it's always working as expected except in this one case (which is also resolved now thanks to Andon M. Coleman).

Comment: @Andreas Because `glTransform` defines a 3D transformation matrix. If you want to select a specific pixel location, it makes more sense to use the functions that actually do that, instead of using a normalized floating point translation factor. And I was pointing you at the relevant functions in the manual.